# Adding numbering for information from database

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using ASP>NET MVC and pulling information from the database and displaying it on a view page. It is working fine but is there any way I can add Index numbers at the start?

For example, at present the display is as follows:

> Name    Age    Gender
>
> Annie   24     Female
>
> Aaron   17     Male

I am looking to make it:

> Index   Name    Age    Gender
>
> 1       Annie   24     Female
>
> 2       Aaron   17     Male

I could have pulled the IDs from the database but they are not necessarily going to be in proper incremental values. I tried and increment via a ViewBag but it doesn't work. Was expected considering the increment was occurring outside the list.. My code as follows at the controller and view.

```
//Controller
public ActionResult Index()
{
    int count = 1;
    ViewBag.Count = count++;
    return View(db.Person.ToList());
}  

    //View
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Index
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender)
            </th>
        </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @ViewBag.Count
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: Do you mean you just want it in the view? If so add `@{ int count = 1; }` and a table column - `<td>@count</td>`  - and increment inside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Feel pretty silly asking the question after you pointed it out.. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the counter in the view (no need for the `ViewBag` property) and increment it inside the loop

```
@{ int counter = 1; }
<table class="table">
   <tr>
        <th>Index</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</th>
        ....
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>@counter</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
            ....
       </tr>
       counter++;
    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "for loop" in razor, something like:

```
@for(var i = 10; i < 21; i++)
{<p>Line @i</p>}
```